# How to map Elastic IP of AWS EC2 Instance with the Domain Name for Ruby Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, amazon-web-services, mapping, a-records

I now want to map my domain name to this web app so that when someone types in the domain name in a browser, it opens the app.

I changed the A-record of my domain to point to the IP address. But this does not work. I don't think we can specify a port number in the A-record?

What change do I need to make to my domain's DNS settings so it points to the rails app without me having to type in the port number?

I have deployed an RoR web app using Passenger. I can access my website with the url: ipaddres:3000.

Thanks.

Comment: You will also be able to access the app at my `http://domain.com:3000`, but it would be more convenient for your users to just run the app on port 80.

Comment: I cannot access it via this url. That is why i also think that its the mapping issue. But i wrote ip address in A record. What else needs to be done?